# How to use resque with the rubber gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

I see that rubber has a bundle for the `resque` gem. If I vulcanize resque, what command would i need to run to create an instance that has the resque_worker and the web interface and the redis database?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this on the rubber mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubber-ec2/qGruh0yCzt0/xtgODGnJxfQJ